# How to convert DefaultMutableTreeNode to Jackson JsonNode?

Tags: java, json, swing, jackson, jtree

I'm trying to write an app that displays a JSON document into a tree format using Swing JTree. I was able to find a way to convert a JSON string to a TreeModel using Jackson but I can't figure out how to convert said TreeModel back to Jackson JsonNode in order to write it to a JSON file. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: I'd advise against using DefaultMutableTreeNode in this case, but instead to create your own JacksonJsonTreeModel, to create the tree from the Json directly, and not through added objects (ie DefaultMutableTreeMode)

Comment: Read on [How to use a DataModel for JTree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#data)

Comment: Thank you both. I decided to implement my own TreeModel as per ConrolAltDel's suggestion and I was able to convert it back to JSON.